# Replacing multiline string between two patterns with sed

Tags: xml, shell

I have a file holding a long single line string between xml tags, i'd like to replace the contents between the tags with sed.

1300_character_long_string_here

The issues i'm having is that sed is not replacing despite that I know my regex is selecting properly. That said even if I am able to select and replace properly I do not know how to pull the replace string (which is roughly as long) from a file and place it.

Here is one of my more successful current attempts at the command:

```
sed 's/\<Tag\>(.*)\<\/Tag\>/REPLACE/g' test.txt> out.txt
```

Although this does not work I can see that is is replacing if I attempt to only replace the first tag.

I should have mentioned at the start that this is an AIX system, not a GNU system.

Comment: Have you tried `'s#\<Tag\>(.*)\<\/Tag\>#REPLACE#g'`?

Comment: searching for `replace multiline string [sed]` returns 14 Q/As. Did you look thru these answers? You'll almost certainly find some good advice. Good luck.

Comment: regular expressions are not suited to modify xml documents

Comment: @Beta I have, no change.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert your substitution text from a file with the `r`command :

```
sed '
/<Tag>.*<\/Tag>/{
r newcontentfile
d
}
' file
```

And don't escape the `<` and `>` in your tags as it's used for [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). It could explain why your pattern doesn't match.

Comment: Right. @KeigaTide You've GOT to understand what effect escaping has on each character. When you escape a meta-character (e.g. `*`) it becomes literal, but when you escape **some** literal characters in some seds they become metacharacters (e.g. `+` or, in this case `<` and `>` becoming word boundaries in GNU sed). If you're not sure then use `[]` to encapsulate a character (e.g. `[<]`) to ensure you're turning a metacharacter into a literal if needed but not accidentally turning a literal into a metacharacter).

Comment: @Kenavoz As written my version of sed cannot parse your solution, I will poke at it.
Word boundaries are something I was unaware of, thank you. That said removing the escape characters caused the regex to select the whole string.

Comment: @KeigaTide The `(` and `)` in your pattern must be used for backreference (you must escape it `\(` and `\)` in basic regex mode). It will not just match  the `<Tag>` contents but the whole string.

Comment: @Kenavoz Escaping the parentheses, not escaping them and removing them entirely all result in matching the whole string. They are not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest something like this:

**File1** contains the replacement text, e.g.

```
some other string
```

**File2** contains the tagged line:

```
...
<tag>some string</tag>
...
```

Now, you can say:

```
sed '1{h;d}; /<tag>/{x;s/^/<tag>/;s/$/<\/tag>/}' File1 File2
```

How this works: First, read the replacement file, place its single line in the hold space and delete it from the output stream. Next, if a line matches `<tag>`, retrieve the replacement text from hold space, and add tags.